# Was Reverend Stynwick trying to give Ichabod a clue?

Tags: sleepy-hollow

In the first scenes of Ichabod being in [Sleepy Hollow (1999)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0162661/?ref_=nv_sr_2), did Reverend Stynwick tell Ichabod the only book they follow is the bible because he was trying to give him a clue or was he trying to be snyde about Ichabod and his scientific methods?

The book contained a family tree graph that Ichabod refers to later in the movie.

Comment: Most probably the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure he was being snide. It's been a while since I watched the movie, but it was Magistrate Philipse that had some sort of change of heart and gave some info away, not Reverend Steenwyck, who remained anti-Ichabod the whole movie.

Also, I don't think he knew the whole plot. More specifically, I don't think he connected the dots, i.e., I think he didn't realize that the return of the Horseman had very earthly motives.